# Python: mmap module's offset argument Exception

Tags: python-2.7, mmap

I'm working with a 1.5 GB File on a 32-Bit windows (and python) and using the mmap module.

As you can see I'm using the parameter `offset=0x5E2030AA` to get the starting point of the data I'm interested in. Since the offset of the mmap.mmap module must be a multiple of `mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY`, I'm using the following function to get the nearest offset:

```py
def getNearestOffset(offset):
    nearest = offset
    nearest -= (offset % mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY)
    return nearest
```

I then seek to the remaining offset by subtracting the passed attribute `offset=0x5E2030AA` from the `nearestOffset`.

```py
def readRIFF(fileno, bufLength=1024**3, offset=0x5E2030AA):
    partialData = False
    previousRIFF = None
    while True:
        nearestOffset = getNearestOffset(offset)
        with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(fileno, bufLength, offset=nearestOffset, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as mm:
            if not partialData:
                mm.seek(offset - nearestOffset)
                startOffset = mm.tell()
                riffID = mm.read(4)
                assert riffID == "RIFF"
                riffSize = toLittleEndianInt(mm.read(4))
                riffType = mm.read(4)
                riffData = mm.read(riffSize - 4)
                # Check for partialData
                if len(riffData) != riffSize - 4:
                    print "DEBUG: Current RIFF blobs trunkated."
                    partialData = True
                    previousRIFF = riffBlob.RiffBlob(riffID, riffSize, riffType, riffData, startOffset)
                    break
```

But when I try to instanciate a new mmap object (in the readRIFF function), I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testRead.py", line 57, in <module>
    readRIFF(f.fileno())
  File "testRead.py", line 28, in readRIFF
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(fileno, bufLength, offset=nearestOffset, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as mm:
WindowsError: [Error 8] Not enough storage is available to process this command
```

I'm confused, why does this exception occur? 
Is there a different way to access my desired offset?
Do I have to modify the length parameter because I try to read more than the file is in size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay seems like I found the answer on my own.

The contextmanager contextlib.closing doesn't actually remove the created memory map from memory (?) and thus my memory is slowly filled with it on each new call.

I fixed the issue by simply deleting the memorymap with `del(mm)` after I'm done extracting relevant data from the blob.